OpenEuler2203 fatal error: 'gnu/stubs-32.h' file not found
On OpenEuler22.03, when I make postgis3.1.0, configure executes correctly.
./configure --prefix=/opt/postgis-3.1.0 --with-pgconfig=/usr/bin/pg_config --with-gdalconfig=/opt/gdal-2.4.2/bin/gdal-config --with-geosconfig=/opt/geos-v3.8.0/bin/geos-config --with-jsondir=/opt/json-c-0.16 --with-projdir=/opt/proj-4.9.3 --without-protobuf

or with options:--disable-multilib
./configure --prefix=/opt/postgis-3.1.0 --with-pgconfig=/usr/bin/pg_config --with-gdalconfig=/opt/gdal-2.4.2/bin/gdal-config --with-geosconfig=/opt/geos-v3.8.0/bin/geos-config --with-jsondir=/opt/json-c-0.16 --with-projdir=/opt/proj-4.9.3 --without-protobuf --disable-multilib

But when execute make,thies error occurs
In file included from /usr/include/pgsql/server/c.h:49:
/usr/include/pgsql/server/postgres_ext.h:47:9: error: unknown type name 'PG_INT64_TYPE'
typedef PG_INT64_TYPE pg_int64;
        ^
In file included from postgis_module.c:26:
In file included from /usr/include/pgsql/server/postgres.h:46:
In file included from /usr/include/pgsql/server/c.h:59:
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:
In file included from /usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h:33:
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:512:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:11: fatal error: 'gnu/stubs-32.h' file not found
# include <gnu/stubs-32.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [/usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/Makefile.global:1060: postgis_module.bc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/gis/postgis-3.1.0/postgis'
make: *** [GNUmakefile:22: all] Error 1

I have tried to install glibc-devel.i686
[root@openeuler2203 postgis-3.1.0]# yum install libstdc++-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:43:17 ago on Tue 09 Apr 2024 12:25:25 PM CST.
Package libstdc++-devel-10.3.1-51.oe2203sp3.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@openeuler2203 postgis-3.1.0]# yum install glibc-devel.i686
Last metadata expiration check: 0:43:46 ago on Tue 09 Apr 2024 12:25:25 PM CST.
No match for argument: glibc-devel.i686
Error: Unable to find a match: glibc-devel.i686
[root@openeuler2203 postgis-3.1.0]# yum install glibc-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:43:53 ago on Tue 09 Apr 2024 12:25:25 PM CST.
Package glibc-devel-2.34-143.oe2203sp3.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@openeuler2203 postgis-3.1.0]# yum install glibc
Last metadata expiration check: 0:44:57 ago on Tue 09 Apr 2024 12:25:25 PM CST.
Package glibc-2.34-143.oe2203sp3.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

The OS is
[root@openeuler2203 postgis-3.1.0]# uname -a
Linux openeuler2203 5.10.0-182.0.0.95.oe2203sp3.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Dec 30 13:10:36 CST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@openeuler2203 postgis-3.1.0]#
[root@openeuler2203 postgis-3.1.0]# cat /etc/openEuler-release
openEuler release 22.03 (LTS-SP3)

Please help me,how to solve this problem?
Thank you very much!
